# Magento 2: Add a new custom input field in order > invoice

Tags: magento2, invoice

I am trying to add a new input field in `Sales > Order > Invoice`, this would be related to the shipping method. This Custom field should be shown in the Invoice Shipping Method section.

I was all ready add field in `sales_order` tabel so we can directly access Like. `$order->getShipmentDetails()`.

[image: order Invoce]

Can someone let me know how I need to proceed with this .

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am loking for same things.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am loking for same things

Answer (score 0):

You can take reference from the below links:-

[Add custom Fields to order](http://tutorialsformagento.blogspot.com/2014/06/add-custom-fields-to-order-and-quote.html)

[creating customer grid](https://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-a-custom-grid-from-scratch/)